# Удаление комментариев из файлов

Tags: c, файлы

Имена исходных файлов сохранены в файле project.txt. На первой строке файла указано целое число N - количество файлов проекта. Далее в файле следует N строк - имена исходных файлов на языке Си. Длина имени с расширением не превышает 32 символа. Все файлы имеют расширение ".c".

Программа должна считать каждый файл исходного кода, удалить из него комментарии, и сохранить результат в новый файл. Имя файла-результата совпадает с исходным, но имеет другое расширение - ".wc"

Обрывается здесь

```c
void rus_text()
{
   // Comment 1

   printf("яяяяяяя", 123, 123);

   /* Comment 2 */

   printf( "Ok" );
}
```

И здесь

```c
void rus_text()
{
   // Comment 1 - яяяя

   printf("Fail", 123, 123);

   /* Comment 2 - яяяя */

   printf( "Ok" );
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)
#define SIZE_NAME 36
int main()
{
    FILE* start_FILE, * first_FILE, * second_FILE;
    int i,n;
    char name_FILE[SIZE_NAME] = { 0 }, x, slash;
    start_FILE = fopen("project.txt", "r");
    fscanf(start_FILE, "%d", &n);
    x = fgetc(start_FILE);
    if (start_FILE == NULL) return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fgets(name_FILE, 35, start_FILE);
        if (name_FILE[strlen(name_FILE) - 1] =='\n' ) name_FILE[strlen(name_FILE) - 1] = '\0';
        first_FILE = fopen(name_FILE, "r");
        if (first_FILE == NULL) return 1;
        int j;
        j = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            while (name_FILE[j] != '.') j++;
            if ((name_FILE[j + 1] != 'c') || (name_FILE[j + 2] != '\0')) j++;
            else break;
        }
        name_FILE[j + 1] = 'w';
        name_FILE[j + 2] = 'c';
        name_FILE[j + 3] = '\0';
        second_FILE = fopen(name_FILE, "w");
        if (second_FILE == NULL) return 1;
        x = fgetc(first_FILE);
        while (x != EOF)
        {
            if (x == '\'')
            {
                fputc(x, second_FILE);
                x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                while ((x != '\'') && (x != '\n') && (x != EOF))
                {
                    if (x == '\\')
                    {
                        fputc(x, second_FILE);
                        x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                        if ((x != '\n') && (x != EOF))
                        {
                            fputc(x, second_FILE);
                            x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                        }
                        else break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fputc(x, second_FILE);
                        x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                    }
                }
                if (x != EOF)
                {
                    fputc(x, second_FILE);
                    x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                }
            }
            else if (x == '\"')
            {
                fputc(x, second_FILE);
                x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                while ((x != '\"') && (x != '\n') && (x != EOF))
                {
                    if (x == '\\')
                    {
                        fputc(x, second_FILE);
                        x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                        if (x != EOF)
                        {
                            fputc(x, second_FILE);
                            x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                        }
                        else break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fputc(x, second_FILE);
                        x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                    }
                }
                if (x != EOF)
                {
                    fputc(x, second_FILE);
                    x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                }
            }
            else if (x == '/')
            {
                slash = x;
                x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                if (x == '/')
                {
                    x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                    while (x != EOF)
                    {
                        if (x == '\\')
                        {
                            x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                            if (x == EOF) break;
                            else if (x == '\n')
                            {
                                fputc(x, second_FILE);
                                x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (x == '\n') break;
                        else
                        {
                            x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                            if (x == '\n') break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (x != EOF)
                    {
                        fputc(x, second_FILE);
                        x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                    }
                }
                else if (x == '*')
                {
                    x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                    while (x != EOF)
                    {
                        if (x == '*')
                        {
                            x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                            if (x == '/')
                            {
                                x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (x == '\n')
                        {
                            fputc(x, second_FILE);
                            x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                        }
                        else if ((x != '*') && (x != '\n')) x = fgetc(first_FILE);
                    }
                }
                else if ((x != '/') && (x != '*'))
                {
                    fputc(slash, second_FILE);
                }
            }
            else if ((x != '\'') && (x != '\"') && (x != '/'))
            {
                fputc(x, second_FILE);
                x = fgetc(first_FILE);
            }
        }
        fclose(first_FILE);
        fclose(second_FILE);
    }
    fclose(start_FILE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что мешает самому проверить?

Comment: У меня всё работает.Не один раз проверял. Но программу не засчитывает.

Comment: Попробуйте ее с собственным текстом (ну, добавьте в оригинал разных комментариев), а потом откомпилируйте полученный текст и запустите его.  Результат работы обеих версий должен совпасть. Это не исчерпывающий, но хороший тест.

Comment: Обе выводят один результат. Мб что-то с открытием файлов? Точку и пробел рассмотрел. Что ещё может помешать?

Comment: Начал смотреть и сразу увидел. Вы проверяете fopen исходного файла после первых действий с ним. Если не открыли -- упали. Исправьте и  проверяйте сами дальше. Проверяйте не только правильные входные данные, но и с разными ошибками (незаконченный комментарий, комментарий внутри комментария, комментарий внутри текстовой константы и т.п.) На чем-то таком вас и срезают

Comment: Глупый вопрос но может си файл открыться, а "wc" нет?

Comment: Может, и вы это проверяете. Возможно, правильным решением в случае ошибки будет не `return 1;`, а `continue;` (и в любом случае при неудаче печатайте сообщение об ошибке (perror())

Comment: Уж сколько раз твердили миру... fgetc/getchar и т.п. (см [man getc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc)) **надо читать в переменную типа** ***`int!!!`*** (а не `char`), тогда буква `я` из кодировки cp-1251 останется равной 255, а не  станет равна -1 (а это код EOF) (поскольку char в x86 signed)